# WPF Application; how to only have one window in the taskbar

Tags: c#, wpf

At the moment my WPF app opens a new icon in the taskbar when a new window is opened like the default. However, I only want one window in the taskbar at anyone time.

Is there a property in the app.xaml that can do this? Or how can I this?

Comment: Do you want to run several instances of your application or is this related to only one application with several windows?

Comment: Do you mean like IE does with tabs? Have the icons grouped by application? Because otherwise, how would people switch from one window to the other?

Answer (score 2):

In all Windows that you don't want to show in taskbar use `ShowInTaskbar="False"`

Example:

```
<Window ShowInTaskbar="False">
    <!-- rest of code -->
</Window>
```

If you want to have only one icon for many instances of the same application then i don't think if this is possible. You can open them inside your application as a new window and set `ShowInTaskbar` programically to achieve something similar.